# Why all the fuss about Doctor Dubble L. Dee?

Tags: short-stories, edgar-allan-poe

In Poe's short story "Three Sundays in a Week" (which can be read in full [here](http://xroads.virginia.edu/%7Ehyper/poe/3sundays.html)), the protagonist and his intended bride need to outwit his uncle, who has decreed that they can only get married "*when three Sundays come together in a week*". They achieve their goal by arranging a conversation with two sea captains who have crossed the International Date Line in opposite directions.

So far, so understandable. What puzzles me is the constant references to one "Doctor Dubble L. Dee". The uncle refers to this gentleman in almost every sentence, but is interrupted by one of the others before he can finish saying anything about him. For example:

> UNCLE. "Yes, yes, yes--I remember it very well--very queer indeed! Both of you gone just one year. A very strange coincidence, indeed! Just what Doctor Dubble L. Dee would denominate an extraordinary concurrence of events. Doctor Dub--"
>
> KATE. [*Interrupting.*] "To be sure, papa, it is something strange; but then Captain Pratt and Captain Smitherton didn't go altogether the same route, and that makes a difference, you know."
>
> UNCLE. "I don't know any such thing, you huzzy! How should I? I think it only makes the matter more remarkable, Doctor Dubble L. Dee--"
>
> KATE. Why, papa, Captain Pratt went round Cape Horn, and Captain Smitherton doubled the Cape of Good Hope."
>
> UNCLE. "Precisely!--the one went east and the other went west, you jade, and they both have gone quite round the world. By the by, Doctor Dubble L. Dee--"

**What does Dubble L. Dee signify? Why does the uncle keep mentioning him, and why do the others keep interrupting every time he does?** Does LLD stand for something relevant?

Comment: the doctor is identified early as a ‘lecturer in quack physics’, It there any more significance than people not wanting to hear the views of a quack? His name may suggest that he only *sounds like* a Doctor of Laws, which is what DLL represents.